# why is use strict rejecting the with

Tags: javascript

['use strict';](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) does not allow me to use [The with statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

What is the reason behind that ?

[image]

```
with (module.init){
    //Detect user device
    detectUserDevice();
    //check if Device is touchable
    isTouchable();
    //check if browser supports webSocket
    webSocket();
    //check if browser supports indexedDB
    indexedDBsupport();
    //check if browser supports localStorage
    checklokalStorage();
}
```

is code-refactoring on this without with possible?

```
//Detect user device
module.init.detectUserDevice();

//check if Device is touchable
module.init.isTouchable();

//check if browser supports webSocket
module.init.webSocket();

//check if browser supports indexedDB
module.init.indexedDBsupport();

//check if browser supports localStorage
module.init.checklokalStorage();
```

Comment: If you'd read either of those links, you'd know the answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict
>   mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose
>   properties you want to access to a temporary variable.

So you could do:

```
var mod = module.init;
mod.detectUserDevice();
mod.isTouchable();
mod.webSocket();
mod.indexedDBsupport();
mod.checklokalStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is prohibited by [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses), that is the reason for the error, so you can't use `with` in `strict mode`

> First, strict mode prohibits with. The problem with with is that any
>   name inside the block might map either to a property of the object
>   passed to it, or to a variable in surrounding (or even global) scope,
>   at runtime: it's impossible to know which beforehand. Strict mode
>   makes with a syntax error, so there's no chance for a name in a with
>   to refer to an unknown location at runtime:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br230269(v=vs.94).aspx